# chatbot window got closed each time after pressed the send message button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I 'm trying to build a chatbot for my Django application. Based on this [tutorial](https://github.com/patrickloeber/chatbot-deployment/blob/main/standalone-frontend/app.js), I have made the following javascript and html. The problem is that after sending each message (pressed send button), the chatbot window get closed. Normally it should only be closed after a discussion is finished. I am not sure what has happened. I tried to use prevent default event method(not sure though if I did it correctly), problem still exists.

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
        this.args = {
            openButton: document.querySelector('.chatbox__button'),
            chatBox: document.querySelector('.chatbox__support'),
            sendButton: document.querySelector('.send__button')
        }

        this.state = false;
        this.messages = [];
    }
  display() {

    
      const {openButton, chatBox, sendButton} = this.args;

        openButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleState(chatBox))

        sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.onSendButton(chatBox))

        const node = chatBox.querySelector('input');
        node.addEventListener("keyup", ({key}) => {
            if (key === "Enter") {
                this.onSendButton(chatBox)
            }
        })
    }

  
    toggleState(chatbox) {
        this.state = !this.state;

        // show or hides the box
        if(this.state) {
            chatbox.classList.add('chatbox--active')
        } else {
            chatbox.classList.remove('chatbox--active')
        }
    }

  onSendButton(chatbox) {
        var textField = chatbox.querySelector('input');
        let text1 = textField.value
        if (text1 === "") {
            return;
        }

        let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 }
        this.messages.push(msg1);

        fetch('/chatbot', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')},
            mode: 'same-origin' //
          })
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(r => {
            let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
            this.messages.push(msg2);
            console.log("msg2")
            this.updateChatText(chatbox)
            console.log("updated chat text")
            textField.value = ''

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            this.updateChatText(chatbox)
            textField.value = ''
          });
    }


  updateChatText(chatbox) {
    
    let html = '';
        this.messages.slice().reverse().forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (item.name === "Sam")
            {
                html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' + item.message + '</div>'
            }
            else
            {
                html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' + item.message + '</div>'
            }
          });
    
    const chatMessages = chatbox.querySelector('.chatbox__messages');
    chatMessages.innerHTML = html + chatMessages.innerHTML;
   // chatMessages.innerHTML = html;
  }

}


const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

Here is the html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bot.css' %}">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Chatbot</title>

    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">

        <div class="chatbox__support">
            <div class="chatbox__header">
                <div class="chatbox__image--header">
                    <img src="https://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/free-social-media-icons-by-uiconstock/png/48x48/Reddit-Icon.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="chatbox__content--header">
                    <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
                    <p class="chatbox__description--header">Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?</p>
                </div>
               
            </div>
           

           
            <div class="chatbox__messages">
               {% for message, response,timestamp in chat_history %}
                   
                    <!-- Response -->
                    {% if response %}
                    <div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">

                        {{ response }}
                        
                    </div>
                     <!-- Message -->
                    <div class="messages__item {% if response %}messages__item--operator{% else %}messages__item--{% endif %}">
                     {{ message }}
                    </div>

                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
               
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__footer">
                
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'chatbot' %}">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                    <!-- Input -->
                    <input type="text" name="message"  class="input" placeholder="Type your message here..."> 

                    
                    <button type="submit" class="chatbox__send__footer send__button" >Send</button>
                </form>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
            <button><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patrickloeber/chatbot-deployment/ce309f3aae1ccc3783059876a1b66e4d7d77ca9f/standalone-frontend/images/chatbox-icon.svg" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bot.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In console, the error message is :
Note:

```
bot.js:69:21 from this line: console.error('Error:', error);
Error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
    onSendButton http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bot.js:69
    (Async: promise callback)
    onSendButton http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bot.js:68
    display http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bot.js:19
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    display http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bot.js:19
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bot.js:99
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get the error, but I have been able to reproduce the error on my machine, and the fix is simple.  Change your button to type button instead of submit:

```html
<button type="button" class="chatbox__send__footer send__button" >Send</button>
```

When the button type is submit, then it will try to send the form the normal route, but you want your JavaScript to handle it instead.  If you had a submit event listener, you would use preventDefault() to prevent the button from causing the form to be submitted the normal, default way.

The way you have it now, the button is both trying to send the form the normal route *and* the JavaScript is also trying to handle the event, and I *think* that is what is causing the issue.

You could leave the button as type submit and then use preventDefault() by giving the button an id:

```html
<button id="send__button" type="submit" class="chatbox__send__footer send__button" >Send</button>
```

And then and adding this to your script, outside of chatbox

```js
document.getElementById('send__button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
```